# parsing in couchdbkit

Tags: python, django, parsing, couchdbkit

The data retrieved from couchdb is the following:

```
{'value': 'UMMC', 'id': 'ef688c440131f59262f2c4f80d001c87', 'key': 'ef688c440131f59262f2c4f80d001c87'}
{'value': 'test', 'id': 'fc2c556010c5167c4a32a7ea4d001d8b', 'key': 'fc2c556010c5167c4a32a7ea4d001d8b'}
{'value': 'Travis', 'id': 'fc2c556010c5167c4a32a7ea4d02889d', 'key': 'fc2c556010c5167c4a32a7ea4d02889d'}
{'value': 'testing', 'id': 'fc2c556010c5167c4a32a7ea4d02b3f8', 'key': 'fc2c556010c5167c4a32a7ea4d02b3f8'}
```

and I am using the following code to extract data

```
projects = db.view('projects/name')
```

My question is: Any way I can parse that output so as to have only test, UMMC, Travis, testing

I looked at the viewresults object from [couchdbkit documentation](http://couchdbkit.org/docs/api/couchdbkit.client.ViewResults-class.html) but  did not find any helpful attributes or functions that I can help parse that output.
I wonder what's out there that I can use.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `json` module, ex:

```
import json
obj = json.loads("{'value': 'UMMC', 'id': 'ef688c440131f59262f2c4f80d001c87', 'key': 'ef688c440131f59262f2c4f80d001c87'}")
# now obj["value"] == "UMMC";
```

Comment: Looks like I would have to convert that output to JSON first? because when I run the above codes I got: 
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for the help.

In my views.py I had the following:

```
projects = db.view('projects/name')
```

and I was trying to display the content of the 'value' attribute in my django template base_site.html

```
{'value': 'UMMC', 'id': 'ef688c440131f59262f2c4f80d001c87', 'key': 'ef688c440131f59262f2c4f80d001c87'}
```

so I did:

```
{%for p in projects%}
   <td>{{p.value }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

And it displayed exactly the content of 'value' attribute,
Again thanks so much, your feedback really guided me.